# Crystal Report always asks for database login

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I need your help.

I'm writing code for a shop program and I am using vb.net 2008 with Crystal Report version 10.5.37xxxx

The problem is when I'm trying to install my program on the client computer, everything works but not in my Crystal Report. It always asks for the database login and I did not code my program to ask for the database login.

I just wrote it in simple code like this:

```
Public Class Form16

    Private Sub Form16_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim view As New CrystalReport4
        view.SetParameterValue("p_1", Form5.no_faktur_tb_immanuel)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = view
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to manually code the login credentials.

```
Public Class Form16

    Private Sub Form16_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim view As New CrystalReport4
        Dim user as string = "Username"
        Dim pwd as string = "Password"

        view.SetDatabaseLogon(user, pwd)
        view.SetParameterValue("p_1", Form5.no_faktur_tb_immanuel)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = view

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i don't know what my username and password, how to set up it?

Comment: if you can open your ms access database without a user and password then you shouldn't need to set one up or include one in your code.  Are you sure the client computer has sufficient privileges?  Also, how are you connecting to your db? Can you post that section of code?

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure your Report `DataSource Provider` is set to `Microsoft OLE DB provider for SQL Server` and not `SQL Server Native Client 10.0`

Comment: i'm using ms access for my database,

Comment: What provider are you using in your Crystal Report?

Comment: Thank you very much. After spending many hours got the working solution. But this should be well documented from the vendor or at least there must be some concrete indication in error message.

Answer (score 0):

try that open field explorer---> database field --->Right Click -->current Data source --->reports connection----->report ----->property ---->
set Property as---

Data Source: .\Databasename.accdb

and code on viewer form load as

Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

```
    Dim Report1 As New rptItemWise

    Dim strServerName As String
    strServerName = Application.StartupPath
rptItemWise.SetDatabaseLogon("admin", "", strServerName, "dastabasename.accdb", True)



    cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\rptItemWise.rpt")
```

also change the report connection same as data source 
i think that code work for you ....

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you!

C# Code :

```cs
ConnectionInfo boconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo ();

boconnectioninfo.ServerName= "D-2818-w2k";

boconnectioninfo.DatabaseName ="NW";

boconnectioninfo.UserID ="sa";

boconnectioninfo.Password ="sa";

CrystalReportViewer1 .ReportSource = Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt");

TableLogOnInfos botableInfo= CrystalReportViewer1 .LogOnInfo;

            foreach (TableLogOnInfo obj2 in botableInfo)


            {
                obj2.ConnectionInfo =boconnectioninfo;

            }
```

Vb.net Code :

```vb
    Dim boconnectioninfo As New ConnectionInfo
        boconnectioninfo.ServerName = "sa"
        boconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "sa"
        boconnectioninfo.UserID = "sa"
        boconnectioninfo.Password = "sa"
        Me.rptViewer.ReportSource = _ReportPath
        Me.rptViewer.SelectionFormula = _SelectionFormula
        If Not _ParameterFields Is Nothing Then
            Me.rptViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = _ParameterFields
        End If
        Dim a As TableLogOnInfos = Me.rptViewer.LogOnInfo





        ' Iterate through the list.
        For Each aa As TableLogOnInfo In a
            aa.ConnectionInfo = boconnectioninfo
        Next

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        rptViewer.Refresh()
```