# Vb.NET 2012 and Crystal Report support packs 12 - always ask for database login

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

need your help about this one..
i'm writing code from vb.net 2013 and Crystal Report SP12 from here http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824.
i'm trying to use record selection and it was running well, but when i add some code to passing a parameter to the Crystal Report, it start to make me dizzy. here are the code for passing the parameter using Parameter fields in Crystal

> Report1.SetParameterValue("Prm_Priority", PassingVar)

And Here are my full code:

> Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
>   Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

and for procedure

> ```
>    Dim A As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
>    Dim B As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
>
>    Report1 = New ReportDocument()
>    Report1.Load("C:\folders\Report1_.rpt")
>
>    For Each A In Report1.Database.Tables
>        B = A.LogOnInfo
>       With B.ConnectionInfo
>            .ServerName = ""
>            .UserID = "someuserid"
>            .Password = "somepassword"
>            .DatabaseName = "someDb"
>        End With
>        A.ApplyLogOnInfo(B)
>    Next A
>    Report1.SetParameterValue("Prm_Priority", Textbox1.text)
>    Report1.RecordSelectionFormula = "{DB.Table} =" & Trim(Textbox2.text)>
>
>    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
> ```

I have read some reference but it seems does not make any deference, the password still came up, here are my reference link:
[Crystal Report always asks for database login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459966/crystal-report-always-asks-for-database-login)
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/73898/Crystal-report-popping-up-login-credential-always
could you guys help me out, am i missing some thing here..Thank you in advance guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need to loop through additional sub reports if you have them and do the same thing (you maybe getting the database login prompt because something additional you're not changing is causing it).  Here is a sub procedure I use that's always worked for me.  Note in this that I've pulled it out of a class so the "Me.ServerName" is coming from a property, you can add that in like you do above.

Also, Crystal Reports through .Net is very finicky about when things are set.  You have to set sub report connections before table connections.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Applies the contents of the ConnectionString property to the report (if it's been set).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub ApplyNewServer(ByVal report As ReportDocument)
        If Me.ServerName = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each subReport As ReportDocument In report.Subreports
            For Each crTable As Table In subReport.Database.Tables
                Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Me.ServerName
                If Me.UseTrustedConnection = True Then
                    loi.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
                Else
                    loi.ConnectionInfo.UserID = Me.Username
                    loi.ConnectionInfo.Password = Me.Password
                End If
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
            Next
        Next
        'Loop through each table in the report and apply the new login information (in our case, a DSN)
        For Each crTable As Table In report.Database.Tables
            Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Me.ServerName
            If Me.UseTrustedConnection = True Then
                loi.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
            Else
                loi.ConnectionInfo.UserID = Me.Username
                loi.ConnectionInfo.Password = Me.Password
            End If
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
            'If your DatabaseName is changing at runtime, specify the table location. 
            'crTable.Location = ci.DatabaseName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        Next
    End Sub
```

http://www.blakepell.com/2010-09-17-crystal-reports-changing-the-database-connection-from-net-subreport-links-and-the-case-of-the-missing-parameter-values

Comment: hi Pell.. you just save my day.. "For Each Subreports As ReportDocument In Report1.Subreports" should have this one too for logging in.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know you linked the other question, but *instead* of doing what you're doing, have you tried to simply do this:

```
crDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "database")
crptViewer.ReportSource = crDocument
```

I only use a `For Each Table in Tables` like you're doing when I have multiple database connections on a single report.